# Almost sure convergence of the longest segment

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Throw $n-1$ points independently at random on an interval of length $1$. Then, the interval is broken up into $n$ segments. Let $Y_n$ be the length of the longest segment. I want to show that $Y_n \rightarrow 0 \ \text{a.s.}$

I think I understand the general idea of how to solve these types of problems. Since the sequence of random variables is monotone, it suffices to show convergence in probability. Since the sequence is non-negative, I just need to bound $P(Y_n > \epsilon)$ for all $\epsilon > 0.$

The proof should be pretty short. I am trying to do something like
$$P(Y_n > \epsilon) \leq P \left ( \bigcup_{i \geq 1} \text{point} \ i \ \text{falls in an interval of length} \  1 - \epsilon  \right ) \leq n(1 - \epsilon)^n.$$
Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your estimate $P(Y_n>\epsilon) \leq  n(1-\epsilon)^{n}$ is correct.

$\sum_n P(Y_n>\epsilon) \leq \sum_n n(1-\epsilon)^{n} <\infty$. By Borel-Cantelli Lemma this implies that with probility $1$, $Y_n <\epsilon$ for all $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but is my computation correct?

Comment: @MathIsLife12 Yes, it is correct. I have edited my answer.